# How to set auto redirect in Paypal sendbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

[image]

[image]

How to show this page after my payment successfully done Auto Redirect within 10 Second

But in current situation Payment is done successfully , but i did not find auto redirect within 10 second , i am running application from local host

Its possible from Local Host i get IPN

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to log into your Sandbox Seller account, click on the "Profile" subtab, and then go to the "Website Preferences" section. The first option will be for Auto-Return.

You can also use this direct URL after you've signed into your Seller account: 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments

Comment: Yes , I have also try to Auto return on , but it not work for Local Host

Comment: Did you pay with a credit card without logging into a PayPal account? Auto-Return only works for people who pay with a PayPal account.

Comment: Hi , i am paying using Paypal Sendbox.